# Package tgheros: numbers in words get different font

Tags: fonts, formatting

I am using the package tgheros. But when I write a word like 'banana5' the number 5 is set in another fontsize than the rest of the word like in this image:

[image]

How can I avoid this behaviour?
My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,norsk]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=25mm,right=25mm,%
bindingoffset=0mm, top=20mm,bottom=20mm}

\linespread{1.3}

\newcommand{\linia}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}

% my own titles
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\begin{center}
\vspace{2ex}
{\huge \textsc{\@title}}
\vspace{1ex}
\\
\linia\\
\@author \hfill \@date
\vspace{4ex}
\end{center}
}
\makeatother
% ...
\title{A new view on banana5}
```

Comment: It is not another fontsize, it is the way the number are set in small caps (try some other to see it and compare with \textup{51234567890}.

Comment: If I use \title{A new view on banana\textup{5}} I get !https://www.dropbox.com/s/vp88yi008ey3m9t/number_font2.jpg?dl=0 - still not pretty.

Comment: Well normally numbers are as large as uppercase letters: B5. You can try to scale the number but probably it will then be too thin.